# Передача переменных из строки и их стирание

Tags: php

В админке реализована функция мульти-добавления постов. Т.е. я выбрал нужные новости чекбоксом, все они получили id в адресной строке вида file.php?page=1&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5
При заходе по этой ссылке в браузере открывается для редактирования новость с id=5. Все гуд, тк и должно быть.
Дальше когда я нажал на кнопку "Добавить новость" мне надо чтобы при обновлении страницы в адресной строке был адрес такой: file.php?page=1&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4 чтобы я смог отредактировать 4-ю новость.

Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Фокус:  
``file.php?page=1&id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=4``

Comment: @xEdelweiss __magic()

Comment: В вопросе какой-то страшный бред.
Почему при редактировании новости с id=5 после нажатия кнопки "Добавить новость" должно произойти редактирование новости с id=4?
Не вижу вообще никакой логики

Answer (score 2):

Если уж речь идет о php тогда видимо:

```
header('location: file.php?page=1&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4');
```

либо:

```
<form action="file.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="2"/>
/*...*/

</form>
```

но во первых подобные вещи реализуются как правило с помощью js, во вторых Вам в скрипт приходит только последнее значение id, а это уже, извините, быдлокодинг...

Answer (score 2):

Сами чекбоксы надо оформить вот так:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='N'>
```

Тогда при (мульти) селекте у вас будет вот такой `request-uri`:
`file.php?page=1&id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=N....`
тут в скрипт приходит массив вида

```
$_GET['id'] == array(
0=>1,
1=>2,
2=>N,....
);
```

обрабатывается такое дело самым обычным `foreach`

```
foreach($_GET['id'] as $key=>$value){ ... }
```

дальше на ваше усмотрение